# Dynamic Oracle Pivot_In_Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm kinda stuck. I want to do a user-role-relationship pivot table and my query so far looks like this:

```
WITH PIVOT_DATA AS (
     SELECT *
     FROM
     (
         SELECT USERNAME, GRANTED_ROLE
         FROM DBA_USERS@DB_LINK U LEFT OUTER JOIN DBA_ROLE_PRIVS@DB_LINK R
         ON U.USERNAME = R.GRANTEE
      )
)
SELECT *
FROM PIVOT_DATA
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(GRANTED_ROLE)
    FOR GRANTED_ROLE
    IN('CONNECT') -- Just an example
)
ORDER BY USERNAME ASC;
```

It works really fine and does the job, but I don't want to write to write any role I want to search for in the `pivot_in_clause`, because we got like tons of them and I don't want to check every time if there are any changes.

So is there a way to write a `SELECT` in the `pivot_in_clause`? I tried it myself:

```
[...]
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(GRANTED_ROLE)
    FOR GRANTED_ROLE
    IN( SELECT ROLE FROM DBA_ROLES@DB_LINK )
)
[...]
```

But it always gives me an ORA-00936: "missing expression" in line 1 of the whole query and I don't know why. Can't there be a `SELECT` in the `pivot_in_clause` or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The problem with your desire it is that the number of columns of result is unpredictable/variable.

Comment: @FlorinGhita: Yes I have to run this script on 5 different database instances and the number of roles is different. That's why I wanted to have a "dynamic" version of this script.

Comment: You can use PIVOT XML and then use (any) as your clause.  The downside is that then it is up to your client to parse the xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build dynamic query in your script,
look at this example:

```
variable rr refcursor

declare 
  bb varchar2(4000);
  cc varchar2( 30000 );
begin 
    WITH PIVOT_DATA AS (
         SELECT *
         FROM
         (
             SELECT USERNAME, GRANTED_ROLE
             FROM DBA_USERS U LEFT OUTER JOIN DBA_ROLE_PRIVS R
             ON U.USERNAME = R.GRANTEE
          )
    )
    select ''''|| listagg( granted_role, ''',''' ) 
            within group( order by granted_role ) || '''' as x 
    into bb
    from (
      select distinct granted_role from pivot_data
    )
    ;

    cc := q'[
    WITH PIVOT_DATA AS (
         SELECT *
         FROM
         (
             SELECT USERNAME, GRANTED_ROLE
             FROM DBA_USERS U LEFT OUTER JOIN DBA_ROLE_PRIVS R
             ON U.USERNAME = R.GRANTEE
          )
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM PIVOT_DATA
    PIVOT
    (
        COUNT(GRANTED_ROLE)
        FOR GRANTED_ROLE
        IN(]'  || bb || q'[) -- Just an example
    )
    ORDER BY USERNAME ASC]';

    open :rr for cc;
end;
/

SET PAGESIZE 200
SET LINESIZE 16000
print :rr
```

Here is the result (only small fragment, because it is very wide and long)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    USERNAME                       'ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK' 'APEX_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE' 'AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE' 'AQ_USER_ROLE'        
    ------------------------------ --------------------------- ------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------
    ANONYMOUS                      0                           0                         0                       0          
    APEX_030200                    0                           0                         0                       0        
    APEX_PUBLIC_USER               0                           0                         0                       0    
    APPQOSSYS                      0                           0                         0                       0   
..............
    IX                             0                           0                         1                       1  
    OWBSYS                         0                           0                         1                       1
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a bunch. That was exactly, what I was looking for. It really does an awesome job. :)