# SQL Counting the number of occurence based on a subject

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, jpql

I find it hard to word what I am trying to achieve. I have a table that looks like this:

```
user char
---------
a | x
a | y
a | z
b | x
b | x
b | y
c | y
c | y
c | z
```

How do I write a query that would return me the following result?

```
user x y z
-------
a |1|1|1|
b |2|1|0|
c |0|2|1|
```

the numbers represent the no of occurences of chars in the original table

EDIT:
The chars values are unknown hence the solution cannot be restricted to these values. Sorry for not mentioning it sooner. I am using Oracle DB but planning to use JPQL to construct the query.

Comment: what db are you using? sql server? mysql?

Comment: What database platform is this for?

Comment: Are the possible `char` values limited to `x`, `y` and `z`, or could they be any character?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this sooner, the char values are unknown hence it can be any character. At Vland and OldProgrammer, I am using oracle DB and will be using JPQL to construct the query

Comment: without using XML, not sure if you can PIVOT with an unknown set of values (assuming you're looking for an SQL only solution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Oracle Pivot\_In\_Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978047/dynamic-oracle-pivot-in-clause)

Answer (score 6):

```
select user,
    sum(case when char='x' then 1 else 0 end) as x,
    sum(case when char='y' then 1 else 0 end) as y,
    sum(case when char='z' then 1 else 0 end) as z
from thetable
group by user
```

Or, if you don't mind stacking vertically, this solution will give you a solution that works even with unknown sets of characters:

```
select user, char, count(*) as count
from thetable
group by user, char
```

This will give you:

```
user   char   count
a      x      1
a      y      1
a      z      1
b      x      2
```

If you want to string an unknown set of values out horizontally (as in your demo output), you're going to need to get into dynamic queries... the SQL standard is not designed to generate output with an unknown number of columns... Hope this is helpful!

Comment: What if he has 250 possible char values?

Comment: Then that should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this sooner, the char values are unknown hence it can be any character.

Comment: Do you definitely need the result strung out horizontally? 'Cause it would be very easy to stack it vertically, even with unknown values.

Comment: Sorry I can't visualize what you mean by stacking it vertically. Would you mind giving me an example of how it would look like? I probably could post-process the data in Java if it is not too far fetched.

Comment: You could have three columns: user, character, and count. So, each row would be a unique user/character combination, with a count of how many times that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using `T-SQL PIVOT (SQL SERVER 2005+)`

```
select *
from userchar as t
pivot
(
    count([char]) for [char] in ([x],[y],[z]) 
) as p
```

Result:

```
user        x           y           z
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
a           1           1           1
b           2           1           0
c           0           2           1

(3 row(s) affected)
```

**Edit ORACLE**:

You can build a similar PIVOT table using [ORACLE](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506).

The *tricky* part is that you need the right column names in the `IN ([x],[y],[z],...)` statement. It shouldn't be too hard to construct the SQL query in code, getting a (`SELECT DISTINCT [char] from table`) and appending it to your base query.

[Pivoting rows into columns dynamically in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730111/pivoting-rows-into-columns-dynamically-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact values on which to PIVOT, you'll either need to do something procedural or mess with dynamic sql (inside an anonymous block), or use XML (in 11g).

If you want the XML approach, it would be something like:

```
with x as (
  select 'a' as usr, 'x' as val from dual
  union all
  select 'a' as usr, 'y' as val from dual
  union all
  select 'b' as usr, 'x' as val from dual
  union all
  select 'b' as usr, 'x' as val from dual
  union all
  select 'c' as usr, 'z' as val from dual
)
select * from x
pivot XML (count(val) as val_cnt for val in (ANY))
;
```

Output:

```
USR VAL_XML
a   <PivotSet><item><column name = "VAL">x</column><column name = "VAL_CNT">1</column></item><item><column name = "VAL">y</column><column name = "VAL_CNT">1</column></item></PivotSet>
b   <PivotSet><item><column name = "VAL">x</column><column name = "VAL_CNT">2</column></item></PivotSet>
c   <PivotSet><item><column name = "VAL">z</column><column name = "VAL_CNT">1</column></item></PivotSet>
```

Hope that helps