# How to transform rows to a single row with columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi.
I'm developing a SQL that transforms rows to a single row.

For example,

```
select key, value from AAA;
```

It may bring the result :

```
==================
Key     |    Value
==================
A1      | P1
A2      | P3
...     | ...
An      | Pn
```

However, I'd like to make it like below

```
=======================================================
C1  |  C2  |  C3  |  C4  | ... | ... |  Cn*2-1  | Cn*2
=======================================================
A1  |  P1  |  A2  |  P2  | ... | ... |  An      | Pn
```

*C1, C2 ... are column names.

Do you have any sparkling idea?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in straight SQL.  Maybe with PL/SQL and SQL combined.

Comment: unlimited? Millions? Zillions? Good luck ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Oracle Pivot\_In\_Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978047/dynamic-oracle-pivot-in-clause)

Comment: The solution linked by Mark J. Bobak would work.However I can not use PL/SQL in my program.

Comment: [Unlimited=Impossible](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where is your C1...Cn... coming from. This example covers the other part: A1 P1...:

```
 SELECT LISTAGG(single_row, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY single_row) AS final_val
  FROM
  (
   SELECT Keys||' '||Val single_row
     FROM
  (
   SELECT 'A1'  Keys, 'P1' Val FROM dual
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A2', 'P3' FROM dual
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A3', 'P4' FROM dual
  )
 )
/

Output:
A1 P1 | A2 P3 | A3 P4
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mention about C1...Cn.... They are the Coulmn's names. So, a single row is completely separated by columns.