# Oracle 11 Transpose Query needed

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a scenario where my data is retrieved as given below

### Product      UOM        Quantity

Petrol       Barrels        13000

Petrol       MT     20000

Diesel       Barrels        7500

Diesel       MT     2500

I need the output in a different output as given below

### Product      Barrels        MT

Petrol       13000          20000

Diesel        7500           2500

Please help me in forming this query, I have been trying this for quite some time without successful result.

Comment: Will there always be 3 columns?  Or is that suppose to be dynamic?

Comment: Hi The columns will be three only, but there can be n no. of rows with different Product, different UOM

Comment: @VasanthKani -- since you don't know the number of UOMs, you're going to need to use Dynamic SQL for that.  There are plenty of examples on SO -- here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978047/dynamic-oracle-pivot-in-clause

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to `PIVOT` your results. Assuming you know the number of columns, one option is to use `MAX` with `CASE`:

```
select product, 
    max(case when uom = 'Barrels' then quantity end) BarrelsQty,
    max(case when uom = 'MT' then quantity end) MTQty
from yourtable
group by product
```