# Move name in one column to multiple colums in SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have two records shown below:

```
Id     User_name   User_id
DT122  Doe, John   123
DT122  Yum, Mi     124
```

How do I write in either Oracle query that can display the result as below

```
Id     UserName1    Username2
DT122  Doe, John    Yum, Mi
```

Any feedback, ideas?

Comment: This isn't a group_concat issue it just looks that way because of the format of names. It is just a cross tab or pivot.

Comment: @SeanLange Pivot probably, question  it is has to be dynamic or not

Comment: You need an **INLINE VIEW**.

Comment: To clarifiy the pivot quesitons: how many ID's are the same each time? Just 2?  if so a simple join would work.  If variable, then you would need to write a Dynamic Pivot statement like [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql) or [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978047/dynamic-oracle-pivot-in-clause)

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I am using oracle

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this in sql server. This is known as a crosstab, some people call this a conditional aggregate. Another option would be to use a PIVOT. I find the syntax for a crosstab less obtuse than pivot and it generally has a very slight advantage for performance.

You can read more about this technique here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/. Or if you don't know how many columns you will need to do a dynamic version of this. You can read about that here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

```
create table #Something
(
    Id char(5)
    , User_name varchar(20)
    , User_id int
)

insert #Something
select 'DT122', 'Doe, John', 123 union all
select 'DT122', 'Yum, Mi', 124

select Id
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 1 then User_Name end) as UserName1
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 2 then User_Name end) as UserName2
from
(
    select ID
        , USER_NAME
        , USER_ID
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY Id order by user_name) as RowNum
    from #Something
) x
group by x.Id

drop table #Something
```